# socket.io express and angularJS errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to install `Socket.io` on my website using ExpressJS and AngularJS

## NodeJS

**server.js**

```
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();

fs = require('fs');

// set our port
var port = 3000; 

// set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

require('./config');

// routes ==================================================
require('./app/routes')(app); // configure our routes

// start app ===============================================
// startup our app at http://localhost:3000
app.listen(port);               


// shoutout to the user                     
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);

// expose app           
exports = module.exports = app;
```

**routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var http = require('http').createServer(app);
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
        console.log('a user connected');

        socket.emit('connection', "Connection created.")
    });
};
```

## AngularJS

**socket.js**

```
angular.module('InterfaceApp.services').factory('socket', [function() {
    var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

    return {
        on: function(eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, callback);
        },
        emit: function(eventName, data) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data);
        }
    };
}]);
```

When starting my server, the console only displays

> Magic happens on port 3000

And in my browser console it polls an error every second (or less)

> POST http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LcsMHH4 404 (Not Found)

What am I missing ? Is it a bad way to use a factory for socket.io ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
fs = require('fs');

// set our port
var port = 3000;

app.set('port', 3000)
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

require('./config');

// routes ==================================================
require('./app/routes')(app, io); // configure our routes

// startup our app at http://localhost:3000
http.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Magic happens on port ' + app.get('port'));
});


// expose app           
exports = module.exports = app;
```

**routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(app, io) {
    io.on('connection', function(x){
        console.log("YEAH");
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it won't work because you are not implementing socket IO properly in routes.js file

According to official site of socket.io you should try something like this.

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

http://socket.io/docs/

Answer (score 0):

where did you use socket.io in your server code ?

check bellow code

```
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

// set our port
var port = 3000;

// set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

require('./config');
var server = http.createServer(app);
// routes ==================================================
require('./app/routes')(app); // configure our routes
var io = socketio.listen(server);
// start app ===============================================
// startup our app at http://localhost:3000
app.listen(port);

 io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // handle connections here 
 });
// shoutout to the user                     
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);

// expose app           
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Why did you comment my require routes ?

Comment: And where do I put `socket.on('connection'...` ?

Comment: I have nothing special inside my `index.html` I just added `socket.io.min.js`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133540/discussion-between-dinesh-and-weedoze).